# Kiosk App - Auto-Update

Tags: application-autoupdate

update on an android device (Samsung Galaxy S2). A I am waiting for the app to download and install. Is there a way I can force this to take place without user interaction.

I was thinking about the following :

1. Killing the app (from another app)
2. Reopening the app after 1 hour (from another app)

Is this going to work? Can I garantee that the update will have taken place?

Thanks in advance!

P.S
I have 700 devices so this has to be automated. I have waited overnight for the app to install while the app was running and it didnt happen. I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app on the play store?

If yes, it should push out an update without user intervention *provided* the setting to 'Auto-update apps' is set, depending on preference of either Wifi or using Mobile data. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this without user interaction (silent install) and without the play store, one of the following items should be addressed:

1. Device must be rooted
2. App must be signed with the OS system signature
3. Device is managed by a MDM preinstalled in the OS (And therefore signed by the OS vendor)

Without one of the above, Android will prompt the user to approve the update. And there will be a Cancel button that you can't control. Keep in mind also that if the uses cancels the upgrade you will fall back to the device launcher.